# Textured 3D model using three.js with <canvas> (not WebGL)

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, textures, three.js

Three.js is commonly used with WebGL, but I am interested in using its CanvasRenderer, because of compatibility issues. However, I require textured models.

I have seen [this one demo](http://three.blackscorp.de/model/index.html), and none else, showing that it is possible to have a textured mesh created in a 3D program and rendered with Three.js. This demo even has animations, but I just need as much as textured meshes.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do this without crafting my own solution. Specifically I'm looking for a way to export from something like Blender and be able to import it with Three.js using the Canvas renderer.

Also, I know the speed implications, I need simple low-poly output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)?

Comment: But, after I export the textured meshes, will they be shown textured even with CanvasRenderer? [This demo](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html) (and other discussions) made me suppose they'll look unskinned (Wow, an answer from you! I'm happy!).

Comment: Example of textured mesh using CanvasRenderer: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html

Comment: But it wasn't exported with the Blender exporter right? Because, in the source code it looks like manually creating a sphere primitive and setting a texture to it. Would it still render textured meshes exported through Blender, in a canvas?

Comment: Indeed, it works. It took me several hours of hair-pulling, and I'm not even sure of what I'm doing, but definitely it works, and I got a model to the canvas. I know you guys already are giving a lot with this amazing library, but, to be honest, documentation is really missed sometimes... And the examples aren't even commented at times. For a 3D novice like me it's kinda steep. Anyway, thank you all very much for how good the library is already :)

Comment: Hi Camilo, Could you please share your work ? Even I am struggling hard to find a way of working with CanvasRenderer and Three.js no WebGL. I was able to create a cube with Texture of image file. My site can be viewed on mobile and it gives response to touch as well. I am trying to use Blender exporter but when the model is exported it creates a lot of file and I am confused what should be used. I think it exports all scene and other things as well.